# ActsAsTaggableOn::DuplicateTagError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, act-as-taggable-on

I am using the act-as-taggable-on gem . I seem to do every thing right but whenever I try to create a tag I get the error:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tags_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 973ms
ActsAsTaggableOn::DuplicateTagError - 'Untag' has already been taken:
```

Comment: Could you add more info? 
Are you adding tags through a controller end-point?